# Emission of a single photon

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

When a **single** photon is emitted as a result of an electronic transition, it will have a defined energy and wavelength. However, its amplitude is not constant over infinite space and time; instead, it is a disturbance of the electromagnetic field originating from the electron. According to Fourier, this wave therefore consists of many different frequencies, corresponding to **many** photons.

Which part of this explanation leads to a contradiction, and is false?

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect that "it will have a defined energy". A single photon is a Fock state, specifically the Fock state with number of photons 1. However, Fock states are [not eigenstates of the energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_state#Fock_states_are_not_energy_eigenstates_in_general). So, they do not have a defined energy, but rather are a superposition of multiple energies.

Answer (score 0):

"it will have a defined energy and wavelength" ... mostly true, but in a laser for example the photons will have a spread say 600nm plus/minus 2nm.

"its amplitude is not constant over infinite space and time"  we can never observe the photon in EM field directly ... we only "see" photons when they are absorbed in our eye/CCD/etc. There is a lot of discussion of how a photon would look in the EM field, the Maxwell equation for photon propagation is pretty good and states the photon has a fixed amplitude in the E field and M field.  Nobody knows if the photon is spread out.

Fourier says we can represent any signal as a sum of sines BUT ... take a bell and ring it, we get the tone and its harmonics, our ear can hear them all.  However take a photon and we can only absorb it by a single atom, i.e. we can never observe the Fourier components of a photon.